# How to delete the empty TAGS while publishing XML in Informatica Target

Tags: xml, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am publishing a XML as Informatica Target and I am getting empty tags in the published file. I have already treid the below mentioned settings but still empty tags are coming.
XML null content representation-> No Tag
XML empty string content representation->No Tag
XML null attribute representation->No Attribute
XML empty string attribute representation->No Attribute
and below mentioned Custom Properties
WriteNullXMLFile=No;SuppressNilContentMethod=ByTree;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this in a KB. Please check if this is applicable in your case.

*When the attribute of an element in the mapping is projected and not the element itself, then when the null is passed to the attribute, the attribute will be suppressed. However, the empty element tag will still be created in the target XML filebecause, the Null Content Representation=No Tag will be in effect only when the element is projected.*

**Solution**

*To suppress the empty element tags, project these elements in the mapping and pass the NULL value*

Answer (score 0):

In session properties go to config object tab. 
In custom properties field write this

```
WriteNullXMLFile = No;SuppressNilContentMethod=ByTree
```

Comment: this will remove empty tags from your tagret XML file

Comment: Dear ETL_GOD, I have already tried that as mentioned in the quesiton and it's not working for me.

Comment: are you using the XSD of you are directly getting data with XML tags ?

Comment: We have a XSD and Using that XSD we're creating the XML Target.

Comment: custom property should work, I have also worked on XML files.
can you check file properties that you have used UTF-8 as output file format format.